# Is there a way to do runtime inspection for django apps? (Any IDE that does this?)

Tags: python, django, ide

I want to do runtime inspection for django apps, meaning, I want to run an app and be able to break/step through/inspect runtime variables.

Is there any IDE that support this or anyway to commandline run django to do this?

I know that the Django shell exists, however, that just sets up an environment and doesn't provide inspection of running code.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wingware's WingIDE supports live inspecting and debugging:
http://wingware.com/ -> http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/django

Edit: It seems that PyScripter has some support for debugging Django too -> http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/

If you're into Eclipse, Pydev also support Django -> http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html

And about WingIDE, you can get a free Professional license for use in an open source project.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a free alternative since I'm not a big spender. I'll try the eclipse pydev combo and see how that works.

Comment: PyScripter is free, also take a look at http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-django/ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with PyCharm from JetBrains.